# Selecting a specific User Certificate on a given URL

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, firefox, robotframework

Below is the sample code which am making use of , upon access of this url am shown a dialog box with the list of user certificates available, here, from the table any one of the user certificates should be selected after that click OK , which takes you to the landing page.

The following is already tried, Handle Alert, Get Window handles and even iframe i.e Select ifarme, after spending few hours it became evident that the issue is as described below.

[image]

## Issue

What is happening here is that the Open Browser line in the below code is not getting completed until i make the appropriate user certificate selection, hence, HELLO1 or any other code is not executed until i make the selection.

Which means that either i need to pass a parameter at the time of URL request itself to make that selection or ??

Does robot framework / selenium support any other way to get the user certificate selected OR using javascript in robot framework.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  OAM OAuth TestSuite
Library SeleniumLibrary
Library String
Library Process
Library Collections
Library json

*** Variables ***
${waittime}=    10s

*** Test Cases ***
SELECT USER CERTIFICATE
    [Tags]  aminhell
    [Documentation]     sample
    ${ID}=    Open Browser     http://wren22uiy.us.iyio.com:8879/odd.html   Chrome      options=add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
    Select Frame    Select a Certificate
    LOG TO CONSOLE  HELLO1
    ${message} =    Get Window handles
    LOG TO CONSOLE  HELLO2
    LOG TO CONSOLE  ${message}
```

Answer (score 1):

After having done a research in this topic, it seems that there is no easy way to solve this situation:

- The Chrome is not easily manageable by AutoIT Library
- The "Open Browser" or any keyword is stuck while the certificate is not selected

I found an "infrastructure" workaround that I would like to share with you consisting on using a proxy that will select the certificate for you. You can install the Nginx and configure make it select the certificate for you, and then test the website directly by HTTP.

The nginx.conf I used:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  0;
    ssl_session_cache  off;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    
    server {
        listen       8335;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8443/;
            proxy_ssl_verify off;
            proxy_ssl_certificate keys/A123456.crt.pem;
            proxy_ssl_certificate_key keys/A123456.key.pem;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen       8336;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://localhost:8443/;
            proxy_ssl_verify off;
            proxy_ssl_certificate keys/B123457.crt.pem;
            proxy_ssl_certificate_key keys/B123457.key.pem;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        }
    }
}
```

HINT: If you use P12 as certificate/key file, it is possible to extract certificate and key by using the following openssl commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out filename.key.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out filename.crt.pem
```

The RF test cases:

```
TESTCASE001 - Certificate for A123456
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
    Open Browser    http://localhost:8335/myapp    Chrome
    Page Should Contain    A123456
    
TESTCASE002 - Certificate for B123457
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers
    Open Browser    http://localhost:8336/myapp    Chrome
    Page Should Contain    B123457
```